# Can Android ID resources refer forwards?

Tags: java, android, build, gradle, android-xml

Can id resources refer to an element later in the file?

Here I have two fields, one for the username, and another for the password. I create a new ID resource (with the `@+id/` syntax) for the password field, but the username field cannot find it in the `android:nextFocusDown` field. I have omitted other fields from the layout xml, because they aren't relevant.

How would I need to declare the IDs in this case?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login_username"
    android:nextFocusDown="@id/login_password" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login_password"
    android:nextFocusUp="@id/login_username"
    android:nextFocusDown="@id/login_submit" />
```

Building with gradle, I'm getting an error that looks like this: `Error:(41, 32) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'nextFocusDown' with value '@id/login_password').`

I do not get an error for `android:nextFocusUp="@id/login_username"` field, which leads me to believe you must declare the id before you use it.

I also get compile errors in my code, because no `R.java` file is being generated, most likely because the resources it builds from aren't building either.

With all the fancy build tools in android, I'm surprised this is a problem. Is this a known problem or desired behavior?

Comment: The resource compiler does not look forward, simply @+id in the first place that uses that id, even if not an "id" field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can pre-generate some ids by creating file values/ids.xml with something like this

```
<resources>
    <item name="login_password" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Here is your case https://stackoverflow.com/a/12247971/4178124

Comment: Knowing that android is open source, could I add something like file scoped ids without it being too much of a bureaucratic process?

Comment: You can use "hack" from @zapl comment, it will works

Answer (score 6):

You can specify a @+id in the first value

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login_username"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/login_password" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login_password"
    android:nextFocusUp="@id/login_username"
    android:nextFocusDown="@id/login_submit" />
```

There is no harm to having multiple @+id's around. It could make detecting typos a bit more difficult, but if you need it, it'll work well.

Comment: Great answer.  To avoid the downside of potential typo as you pointed out, one could omit "+" for the second id so that only one "+" for each id.